# Why isn't inheritance working properly when embedding python in a C++ application?

Tags: python, c++

I'd asked this question [on another forum](https://sourceforge.net/p/pythonqt/discussion/631393/thread/862ff73f88/?limit=25#aaf7), but apparently this issue is more generically python-related than I'd thought.  Weirdly enough, I haven't been able to find too many topics on this particular issue.

Essentially, I have a base class in base.py:

```
class B:
   def __init__(self):
       ...
   def func(self):
       ...
```

And a child class in child.py:

```
from base import B

class C(B):
   def __init__(self):
       B.__init__(self)
       ...
   def func(self):
       B.func(self)
       ...
```

If I make these classes and call them purely through Python, everything works fine.  However, when I try to do so through the C API, C.func() fails to call B.func(). It's almost as if C.func() is ignoring the line where I call `B.func(self)` entirely.

I am defining these classes via the C API by loading the contents of base.py and child.py into strings. This is done via Qt through a loadFromFile routine, and I am confident that this is working correctly. I am then calling the code that I've loaded for each class through a function that wraps `PyRun_SimpleString`:

```
bool PythonAPI::runCode(const std::string& code)
{
    int ran = PyRun_SimpleString(code.c_str());
    if (ran < 0) {
        printErrors();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

So my routine to instantiate a Child instance and run a method if it is essentially:

```
// Initialize interpreter
Py_Initialize();

// Initialize main module
PyObject* mainModule = PyImport_AddModule("__main__");

// Load in code frombase.py and child.py
std::string baseCode = loadFromFile(base.py);
std::string childCode = loadFromFile(child.py);

// Define classes by running code
runCode(baseCode);
runCode(childCode);

// Obtain Child class from python and instantiate
PyObject* cls = PyObject_GetAttrString(mainModule, "Child");
PyObject* instance= PyObject_CallObject(cls, argList);

// Call routine of child instance
PyObject* result = call(instance, func, NULL);
```

Is there any strangeness with how the API works that could cause this to be the case? My routine to call methods of a class instance (minus the error handling) looks like this:

```
PyObject * PythonAPI::call(PyObject * instance, const std::string& methodName, PyObject * args)
{
    // Obtain pointer to function
    PyObject* method = PyObject_GetAttrString(instance, methodName.c_str());

    // Call function
    PyObject* output = PyObject_CallObject(method, args);

    // Decrement count for function, ignoring if it is null
    Py_XDECREF(method);

    return output;
}
```

I'd like for users of my application to interface purely through Python, which is why I want to pack everything they would need into the class B, from which they could inherit. Thanks!

Edit:  After much investigation, it seems that inheritance works just fine when class B and C are in the same file.  However, I need class B to be in its own file due to the constraints of the project, so I can't use this workaround.  I'm not sure why this would cause problems.

Comment: What is `o`? I don't see enough information here to diagnose the problem.

Comment: There's stuff here that doesn't make sense, and stuff that's missing, and overall, it looks like you tried to simplify things (which is good) but didn't know how to do so properly (which is a skill you should try to learn), leaving us with something that only bears a vague resemblance to your code, and not in the ways it needs to. When building a simplified version of your code, the result needs to be *runnable* and needs to *reproduce the error when run*, without needing any hidden context.

Comment: Looking at what you posted on SourceForge, I suspect you may be on Python 2, where classes behave differently by default and 0-argument `super` isn't a thing. The code you posted on SourceForge used 0-argument `super`.

Comment: Hi @user2357112 supports Monica, I did put this question together a bit too haphazardly, sorry about that.  I was a bit more extensive in my other forum post, but I've edited this question so my process should be more clear.  Additionally, I am using python 3.8, and am now making explicit calls to the parent class instead of using super().  Still no dice.

Comment: Well, the new version still isn't runnable, but it suggests its own entirely new set of problems. The module handling in what you've posted makes no sense. It looks like you're running everything in the context of `__main__` instead of actually importing modules. Do you know you can import modules in the Python C API? https://docs.python.org/3.8/c-api/import.html

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, I can't duplicate too much of the code due to the proprietary nature of the source, so I can only give snippets that provide the gist.  I'm thinking that my module handling might be a major problem, given that I didn't think there were any problems with running everything in the context of __main__.  Is this bad practice?  What is the alternative?  I'm not really familiar with what the usage of PyImport_ImportModule is supposed to be, or how it differs from defining and instantiating classes in __main__.

Comment: Sorry @user2357112 supports Monica, forgot to tag you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204162/discussion-between-danny-and-user2357112-supports-monica).